# H2 csvread encrypt

Tags: encryption, h2

H2-folks,
I have a H2-Database-Table like this:

```
   CREATE TABLE Achimv  
               (
                NAME     CHAR(10)         
              , VORNAME  CHAR(10)
              , PLZ      CHAR(10)          
               )
   ;
```

and I have got a CSV-File with '$' as row separators:

```
 Berger $Willi$26531
 Meyer  $Hans $85322
 Klausen$Till $52389
```

and the INSERT-Statements work perfectly as follows:

```
   INSERT INTO Achimv 
   SELECT * FROM CSVREAD 
                 ('E:/Achimv.csv',
                  ' NAME
                  $ VORNAME
                  $ PLZ
                  ', 'charset=UTF-8 fieldSeparator=$');
```

But now the table should be filled with the first two rows being 
AES-encrypted and the third one not.

My modification (done like in the H2-Dokumentation-pdf):

```
. . . . . 

             ('E:/Achimv.csv',
              ' ENCRYPT('AES', '00', STRINGTOUTF8(NAME))
              $ ENCRYPT('AES', '00', STRINGTOUTF8(VORNAME))
              $ PLZ
              ', 'charset=UTF-8 fieldSeparator=$');
```

ended with a SQL-Syntax-Error:

```
. . .
 ' ENCRYPT('AES[*]', '00', STRINGTOUTF8(NAME))
```

How is it possible to load CSV-data with CSVREAD **in combination with** ENCRYT **?**

Thanks in advance

Achim

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO Achimv 
SELECT 
  ENCRYPT('AES', '00', STRINGTOUTF8(NAME)),
  ENCRYPT('AES', '00', STRINGTOUTF8(VORNAME)),
  PLZ
FROM CSVREAD 
             ('E:/Achimv.csv',
              ' NAME
              $ VORNAME
              $ PLZ
              ', 'charset=UTF-8 fieldSeparator=$');
```

Comment: @ Thomas : Thanks for the quick and helpful response!